# google cloud storage java client set timeout for getContent

Tags: google-cloud-storage

how can I set a timeout for GCS blob fetching?

There is timeout options in the python client sdk, but I've googled around for similar options in JAVA, wasn't being able to find one.
I'm using kotlin, and here is how i was getting the content

```kotlin
        val storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().service
        val blob = storage.get(buckName).get(blobName)
        return blob.getContent()
```

Comment: Might this be what you are looking for?  ... https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors

Comment: this one is for google analytics. and I've just updated the code i was doing things, no HTTPClient involved at all

Comment: You can't customize this in the source. There is a RPCTimeout but you can't override it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change some options, rather than using the default `StorageOptions`:

```kotlin
val transport_options = StorageOptions.getDefaultHttpTransportOptions().toBuilder().setConnectTimeout(1234).setReadTimeout(4321).build()
// timeouts are in ms
val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setTransportOptions(transport_options).build()
```